# Character.IsDigit returns false instead of true on an integer Java

Tags: java, string, integer, type-conversion, syntax-error

Hi I am newer to programming so I need some help. I need to make a method where I check if a birthday is correct. For instance 960214 where 96 is year 02 is month and 14 is day, but the birthday is a String. So here is what I got:

```
private static boolean checkCorrect(String a) {

    int year = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0,2));

    int month = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(2, 4));

    int day = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(4, 6));

    if (a.length() == 6 && Character.isDigit(year)) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Now I stopped at Character.isDigit(year) because it returns false where it should return true. I printed year just to see what comes out and 96 comes out just like in the example on top. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you *read* the javadoc of [`Character.isDigit(int codePoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-int-)? *Determines if the **specified character (Unicode code point)** is a digit*. `year` is a number, not a Unicode code point.

Comment: Like I said I am newer to programming I read something where it says "true if the character is a digit; false otherwise." isn't a number a digit ?

Comment: I can't even imagine what you think `isDigit()` would do for a number? How can a number *not* be "digits"? Besides, you just said it yourself: *"true if the **character** is a digit; false otherwise."*

Comment: If you're trying to verify if `a` is a string of 6 digits, you should probably: 1) Check the length *before* calling [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), or you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. 2) Check if characters are digits *before* calling [`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), or you get a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: But still lets assume that the length is good and the characters are numbers why do I get false as a return ? I still don't get it ...

Comment: Because the *decimal number* `2016`, is Unicode code point ['NKO LETTER NA WOLOSO' (U+07E0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/07e0/index.htm), which looks like this: `ߠ`. That is not a digit character.

Comment: Oooh I see now thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, more on point: Because the *decimal number* `96`, is Unicode code point [''GRAVE ACCENT' (U+0060)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm), which looks like this: `\``. That is not a digit character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character.isDigit(year) excepts a char not a number.
Character.isDigit('5') this will return true.

Comment: But that is for char for about Character.isDigit(int CodePoint) can you explain to me briefly what that is ?

Comment: see this link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isdigit.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Write your Birthday in the form yymmdd: ");
    String date = input.nextLine();
    if(checkDate(date))
      System.out.println("Your Birthday: " + date + " is valid :)");
    else
      System.out.println("Your Birthday: " + date + " is invalid :(");
  }

  public static Boolean checkDate(String date){
    if(date.length() != 6) {
      System.err.println("Please enter your Birthday in the form yymmdd... ");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
      int year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2));
      int month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(2, 4));
      int day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(4, 6));
      if ((00<=year && year<=99) && (01<=month && month<=12) && (01<day && day<=31)) 
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/E8X0/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

If I understand correctly, you want to make sure that the inputted String is a number. The following code should if that is the issue.

**Advice:**

You should check if it is a number before parsing the Integer, because if you parse it immediately and it is invalid, it will cause an Exception.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "960214"; // Sets the value of the String
    String year = input.substring(0, 2); // Finds the "year" value in the
                                            // input
    Boolean isANumber = true; // The year is thought to be a number unless
                                // proven otherwise
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(year); // Tries to parse the year into an integer
    } catch (Exception ex) { // Catches an Exception if one occurs (which
                                // would mean that the year is not an
                                // integer
        isANumber = false; // Sets the value of "isANumber" to false
    }
    if (isANumber) { // If it is a number...
        System.out.println(year + " is a number!"); // Say it is a number
    } else {
        System.out.println(year + " is not a number!"); // Say it is not a
                                                        // number
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
96 is a number!
```

**Output (When the "input" is "xx0214"):**

```
xx is not a number!
```